# Share Road Closures with Waze with JSON REST Endpoint

Tags: json, endpoint, waze

I am CCP member with Waze. I would like to know if it is possible to use my ArcGIS Server REST endpoint, in JSON format, to share data with Waze regarding closed roads? I know that you can share a JSON file on  a server, that is periodically written to, for Waze to poll. Just want to know if my endpoint URL can work (much easier).

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer out of my own experience, but I know that ArcGIS has worked together with Waze to provide [a couple of solutions that should make your life easier](https://working-with-waze.hub.arcgis.com/).

ArcGIS [has created a template](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-solutions/reference/introduction-to-road-closures.htm) that provides road closures in the [Common Internet File Structure (CIFS)](https://developers.google.com/waze/data-feed/road-closure-information) format that Waze expects. It is not exactly the same as using the existing REST endpoint, but seems to use a Solution to generate this data.

Hopefully that is a practical solution or at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you! That is useful information. Two questions: 
1) I assume that the database field names in the ArcGIS Solution do not have to be exactly the same as the CIFS? I compared the two and while the ArcGIS Solutions schema is more or less the same, the field names are not exact. 
2)Do you know if anyone has fed this feature service directly into the Waze CCP portal? That is whithout having to use this feature service to update a JSON file, then provide the JSON file to Waze?

Comment: @GeneSipes I think it will always be safest to follow the field names that Waze has listed on their site. If I'm not mistaken, the Waze for Cities portal (CCP is the old name ;)) has a documentation section where more details can be found. I'd expect that to be the best source of information.

I personally have no experience with that aspect of the Waze for Cities program though, so I'm afraid I can't be of much more help than that.